# React - Browser's Back button doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

In the following component, if I click on any of the two buttons, the URL in the address-bar gets changed.

In the list view if you click on the button **Details** the page get rendered and shows that particular item and the URL in the address bar get changed too.
And in the user view if you click on the "Back to overview" button, the page renders back to the list view and the URL gets changed again.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me'
    )
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  const renderItem = (item, userId) => {
    const setURL = (e) => {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, '/' + e)
      setID(item.login.uuid)
    }

    const clearURL = (e) => {
      window.history.back()
      setID(null)
    }

    return (
      <Fragment key={item.login.uuid}>
        {userId ? (
          // User view
            <div>
              <img src={item.picture.large} />
              <h2>
                {item.name.first}
              </h2>
              <p>
                {item.phone}
                <br />
                {item.email}
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => clearURL('/')}>
                Back to overview
              </button>
            </div>
        ) : (
          // List view
          <li>
              <img src={item.picture.large} />
              <h2>
                {item.name.first}                 
              </h2>
              <button onClick={() => setURL(item.login.uuid)}>
                Details
              </button>
          </li>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }

  const user = resources.find(user => user.login.uuid === id)

  if (user) {
    // User view
    return <div>{renderItem(user, true)}</div>
  } else {
    // List view
    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          {resources.map(user => renderItem(user, false))}
        </ul>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default UserList
```

Everything is working fine.

However, the problem with this solution is that on user view, I cannot use the browsers back button to go back to the list view page. 
Is there any way I can change this without using React Route?

Answer (score 0):

So what I believe is happening is you are over-writing the 'history' of the browser. The 'history' is pretty much just a stack of paths you've been and when you click the back button it just pops the current path off the stack. I think that when your using 'window.history.pushState(null, null, '/' + e)' its setting the history = to null so there is nothing to go back to. I would recommend using react-router and just pushing a path ie. router.push('/whatever'). There are a bunch of ways to interact with the history through react without using the native history object. If you want to use the native history object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Edit - I apologize your not overwritting the history, but I do still believe that the error is coming from passing a 'null' value as the 'state' param for the pushState method